# Boost signaling between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, signals, signals-slots

For the better part of the last few hours I've been trying to get a clue on how to approach this problem - I have an application where I need to get information from a thread into some intermediary module, which then sends it to the Qt GUI using Qt signals (which I've previously used, but only inside a Qt GUI). So now I'm facing this issue - I have a thread that does some processing, for example :

```
class TrialLogic
{
public:

    void operator()();
    TrialLogic(TrialModel *m);
    ~TrialLogic();

private:

    TrialModel *model;

    void emitSignal();

    int testNum;

};
```

When the class TrialLogic is created, it is given the pointer to TrialModel, which does some additional processing before passing them to the GUI.

Now here's the problem - how do I get my thread to emit a signal that, for example, passes the testNum value to the TrialModel class, which has a function that can take the testNum as an argument?

Comment: I think what you want is a condition variable. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable. If you want values to change to be atomic when checked, but no sigals, try atomic. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking really.  You can just call `model->someFunc(testNum);` to pass `testNum` to `model`.  Unless `TrialModel` has some background thread sitting around waiting for signals, then they probably aren't the correct mechanism here.

Comment: @MilesBudnek , the model can also needs to process incoming data from the GUI (buttonpresses and field information) - would this still be viable? the logic will in reality have 2 sub-threads, one of which interfaces with hardware and the other that contains logic itself, but that part already works nicely.